# AD single sign-on mechanism for chatbot in microsoft bot framework

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

we need some help in Azure AD single sign-on mechanism...we have our own procured enterprise azure subscription on which we have published our chatbot....client has its own procured azure license and its applications are integrated with AD for single sign-on....is there any artcile or mechanism through which we can make our chatbot work as single sign-on when deployed in client's environment as a weblink in one of their portals?

We're using bot framework v3 and we've tried AD OTP mechanism but client wants single sign-on to be implemented in their environment

Comment: @gagandeepsignh, regarding v3 I have not seen any documentation that had solved the issue of SSO experience, however there is current discussion regarding the topic in the BotFramework-WebChat repo here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1564 . It provides guidelines of how you can start working towards the solution, however the ticket is still open for the team to eventually create a sample for users to model after

Comment: There was also an official MSFT blog posted as of last year that said SSO was "still in development", but also detailed the diff. sign-in experiences the BF offers so far: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/sign-in-experiences/

Comment: Ok, got confirmation from someone who works on Authorization on the BF team directly. Says "We are not working on any additional SSO capabilities currently. We should update the blog post to say that". Best to do right now for guidance is to watch the GH issue I linked above, as the WebChat team has outlined so advice currently, and eventually seem to want to create a sample with SSO using AAD